# Regex to Match a bunch of character + only a single |

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that works great for matching the following..

```
^[a-z-&+/]
```

Now I want add in a match for the "|" symbol, but only if it starts with a single "|"

True results

```
|hello
apple
test||test
```

False Results

```
||hello
```

I tried a bunch of ways on regex101.com - but I can't come up with the right regex.

Comment: Well, `^(?<![|][|])[a-z-&+/|]+` would match your examples. But your description is unclear/contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
                      /^[|a-z-&+/](?!\|)/
```

One can use | inside character set as well.
Check http://www.regexr.com/3coad where i tested the match.

Comment: Yes, this works as well, I think this is a better answer - because it takes less steps.

Answer (score 2):

This regex works for what you want:

```
^([a-z-&+\/]|\|(?!\|))
```

This goes from the start of the input, tries to find any of your original characters (`[a-z-&+/]`) OR a `|` not followed by a `|` (using a negative lookahead).

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xS9gH8/1).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. You saved me a ton of time.